# Using VBA to change color of single word in string of Word document table to match cell color

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have Word documents with tables that have color coded cells in which I would like to "hide" certain words of each cell by changing their color to match the cell color.

I have a VBA script that searches for the words from an array list and successfully finds them, but I can't get those words to change color to the cell background color.

```
Sub TableWordColorReplace()

Dim C As Cell
Dim tableCount As Long
Dim Ctr As Integer
Dim backColor As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim range As range
Dim TargetList

tableCount = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count  'to account for any/all tables in the document

TargetList = Array("word1", "word2", "word3")


For Ctr = 1 To tableCount  'cycle thru each table in the document
    For Each C In ActiveDocument.Tables(Ctr).range.Cells  'search in every cell in the table
        backColor = C.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor  'the color I want to change the found text to
        For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)  'cycle thru each word in the list
            With C.range.Find
                .Text = TargetList(i)
                With .Replacement
                    .Text = TargetList(i)
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Font.Color = backColor  'this is where I expect the word color to change, but it doesn't
                End With
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next
    Next C
Next Ctr

End Sub
```

My expectation is that when the word is found in any cell, the .Replacement section of code will change the word color to the backColor variable value, but the text color does not change.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are facing is your cell color is not set to anything, and being on the default colour `-16777216` (which is the same as `wdColorAutomatic`) , you are setting the automatic color to your text as well (which is generally black).

If your cells background are always white, you can do `.Font.Color = wdColorWhite`, otherwise you can make a check against the default value, i.e.:

```vb
...
        backColor = C.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor  'the color I want to change the found text to
        If backColor = -16777216 Then backColor = wdColorWhite
...
```

Otherwise if there is any color set on the background, it will use that.

Comment: The cell color is something that has been set by the user (typically to a non-white shade).  So in one instance a row of cells is a shade of gray with a backColor value of -603923969.
I will add this... today I tried running the code again and it just worked.  I don't recall changing anything prior to it not working yesterday so I think it's done.

Comment: Well, that was my guess, given it was the only time when your code wouldn't "work" in my tests. Glad is resolved for you though.